# CDI Programmatic lookup exception (InjectionPoint)

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm confronting to a bug on my TomEE server. The CDI dynamic lookup doesn't work as planned.

Especially when the bean i want to look up is produced by a factory (@Produces) with the InjectionPoint as parameter.

Here is a simple example of my problem.

**The Qualifier @RandomNumber**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE })
public @interface RandomNumber {

@Nonbinding
int min() default 0;

@Nonbinding
int max() default 10; 
}
```

**His Literal RandomNumerLiteral**

```
public class RandomNumberLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<RandomNumber> implements RandomNumber {

private final int   min;

private final int   max;

public RandomNumberLiteral(final int min, final int max) {

    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public int max() {

    return this.max;
}

@Override
public int min() {

    return this.min;
}

}
```

**The Factory method (POJO)**

```
@Produces
@RandomNumber
public Integer producesNumber(final InjectionPoint ip) {

final int min = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(RandomNumber.class).min();
final int max = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(RandomNumber.class).max();

return (new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
}
```

**The test class (the select result of the dynamic lookup is neither ambiguous nor unsatisfied)**

```
public class Test {

@Inject
@RandomNumber(min = 20, max = 50)
private Integer                         random;

@Inject
@Any
private Instance<Integer>               randomInstance;

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Random1: " + this.random);
    System.out.println("Random2: " + this.randomInstance.select(new RandomNumberLiteral(20,50)).get());
}
}
```

**The first statement is working fine but for the second i got an exception:**

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
java.util.EmptyStackException
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:363)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)

blablabla

Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.InjectionPointBean.createInstance(InjectionPointBean.java:83)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.InjectionPointBean.createInstance(InjectionPointBean.java:28)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.create(AbstractOwbBean.java:186)
at org.apache.webbeans.context.DependentContext.getInstance(DependentContext.java:70)
at org.apache.webbeans.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:132)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:872)
at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableMethods.doInjection(InjectableMethods.java:96)
at        org.apache.webbeans.component.ProducerMethodBean.createDefaultInstance(ProducerMethodBean.java:161)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.ProducerMethodBean.createInstance(ProducerMethodBean.java:123)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.createNewInstance(AbstractOwbBean.java:233)
at org.apache.webbeans.portable.creation.AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducer.java:77)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.InjectionTargetWrapper.produce(InjectionTargetWrapper.java:133)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.create(AbstractOwbBean.java:180)
at org.apache.webbeans.context.DependentContext.getInstance(DependentContext.java:70)
at org.apache.webbeans.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:132)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:872)
at org.apache.webbeans.inject.instance.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:126)
```

I need help!
Thanks everybody !

Comment: what version of tomee are you using?

Comment: Hi it's the 1.5.1 version.

Comment: I think there is a technical impossibility to inject the InjectionPoint because there is not really an InjectionPoint (i'm using dynamic lookup).

Comment: You're generally correct.  This was addressed in OWB 1.2.1 (I believe) which if you upgrade to TomEE 1.7.x should be included.